# Increase image resolution using MetaUML and metapost

Tags: graphics, conversion, metapost, metauml

I'm using MetaUML to create text-driven UML diagrams. When I generate a figure, with:

```
$ mpost example.mp
$ convert ps:example.1 png:example.png
```

a very low-resolution image is generated. If I scale the postscript image up using ImageMagick's `convert` utility, it is blurry (obviously sampled up from low-res source data). Additionally, if I change the `defaultscale` parameter in the MetaUML source, all text will be increased in size but it will overlap with other text. Additionally at large values for `defaultscale`, the text will extend beyond the UML boxes.

Here's the complete MetaUML source I'm using:

```
prologues := 2; % needed to load font definitions
defaultscale := 1.0 % I tweaking this value doesn't do what I want
input metauml; % load the MetaUML library
  beginfig(1);
    Class.A("Object")()();
    Class.B("Point") % class name
        ("#x:int", "#y:int") % attributes
        ("+set(x:int, y:int)", % operations
        "+getX():int",
        "+getY():int",
        "-debug():void");
    B.e = A.w + (-20, 0);
    drawObjects(A, B);
    link(inheritance)(B.e -- A.w);
  endfig;
end
```

How do I make the pipeline (MetaUML -> Metapost -> convert) yield higher resolution images?

Comment: `convert -quality 90 -density 600 ps:example.1 png:example.png` would be better, probably.

Comment: @egreg - That absolutely did it. Post as an answer and you win!

Comment: I wonder why you create a vector image and then rasterise it?

Comment: @Marco - The end goal is a PNG. I'm not familiar with this toolchain. What would you recommend?

Comment: Don't rasterise a vector image if not strictly required. Depending on your requirements you can convert it to PDF, PostScript or SVG. I personally mostly go for PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather convert the Postscript file to PDF, so you don't lose vector information. Use a bitmap format such as PNG only if there's no other choice.

You can improve the result of the bitmap file by running `convert` with a high `-density` parameter, and also by using a high `-quality`:

```
convert -quality 90 -density 600 ps:example.1 png:example.png
```

This will create a 600dpi image, rather than the default 72dpi.